# Not able to link `gtk+3` on OSX after installing it with brew

Tags: macos, gtk, homebrew

I installed `gtk+3` on OSX El Capitan with homebrew. The install worked fine, expect for the linking part.

```
npie5f587:applications v$ brew link gtk+3
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/gtk+3/3.18.6...
Error: Could not symlink share/applications/gtk3-demo.desktop
/usr/local/share/applications is not writable.
```

I've already tried using `chown` on `/usr/local` to no success.

Comment: What does `ls -ld /usr/local/share/applications` say? I find it weird that Homebrew would create a nonwritable directory...

Comment: it should belong to you, group `admin`, with permissions: `drwxr-xr-x`

Comment: It says: `drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel   102B Oct  4 15:08 /usr/local/share/applications/`. Maybe I used `chown` wrong?

Comment: so `chown` it to you.

Comment: Use `chown -R` to apply it recursively on the whole tree.

Answer (score 0):

El Capitan has a thing called System Integrity Protection that prevents you from writing to system directories such as `/usr`. There is an exception made for `/usr/local`, but at least for me, the first time I used Homebrew on El Capitan I had to do some `chown`ing.

See Homebrew's documentation on the subject: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/El_Capitan_and_Homebrew.md tl;dr, use `chown -R`.